# Displaying different MIME types in a browser

Tags: html, css, mime-types

I am looking at writing a browser application, that can display content that is of different MIME types. The main content types are application, message, image, audio and multipart.

Now, I do not know a lot about the different content types, and how it will be handled by the browser. Most clients will use Chrome, so answers relating to Chrome will be great. The content will be provided by the client, so my main concern at this point is the display thereof.

My idea at the moment is to have an iframe within my browser application, and this iframe will get the value of the content that needs to be displayed. Is this necessarily a good ideas or are there any better alternative solutions?

I have two related questions at this moment:

1. Will the browser change the display according to the MIME type?
2. Do I have to specify the CSS for each MIME type I would like to support?

If if sounds as if I have no clue, it is probably because I don't :) that is why I think it would be good to have a discussion with someone who knows a bit more.

Thanks!

Comment: display different mime types... What??? Mime type is just a string which is supposed to identify the type of the content of the file. That is why your question is absolutely not clear.

Comment: Yes, display content of different MIME types. Though syntactically I could structure the question differently I do think it get the issue at hand across. I will have a html file, and in this html file I would like to be able to load content of different MIME types, and have it displayed nicely.

Answer (score 0):

For browser to display some file content you must properly set `Content-Type` headers. You can't do that using html/css. Use some back-end language like PHP.

```
$path = 'uploads/1554/my_uploaded.jpg';
$mime = mime_content_type($path);
header('Content-Type: '.$mime); // "Content-Type: image/jpg"
echo file_get_contents($path);

exit();
```

---

Properly validate user uploaded files, at it may contain some malicious code that can expose access to your system.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. What other technology can be used for this except PHP? In my project I am currently using html/css/jquery; Is there a php alternative that I can research on how to do it in?

Comment: @Harriet Here is plenty of them: https://www.quora.com/Which-programming-languages-are-front-end-and-which-ones-are-back-end

All you need is set headers and output file content.

Also maybe you can simply set `iFrame` source directly to file and let browser handle it's display (if it's PDF, image or video)